# Google SpeechClient io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Credentials failed to obtain metadata

Tags: java, google-speech-api

I'm making an application with Google SpeechClient that has the requirements to set a GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable that, once set, you can use the voice to text api.

My application is required to run in linux and windows. In linux it runs perfectly, however, on windows, when running the project, it throws an exception com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: "io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Credentials failed to obtain metadata" when trying to run this thread

```
package Controller.Runnables;

import Controller.GUI.VoxSpeechGUIController;
import Model.SpokenTextHistory;
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientStream;
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ResponseObserver;
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.StreamController;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.*;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SpeechRecognizerRunnable implements Runnable{

    private VoxSpeechGUIController controller;

    public SpeechRecognizerRunnable(VoxSpeechGUIController voxSpeechGUIController) {
        this.controller = voxSpeechGUIController;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        MicrofoneRunnable micrunnable = MicrofoneRunnable.getInstance();
        Thread micThread = new Thread(micrunnable);
        ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responseObserver = null;
        try (SpeechClient client = SpeechClient.create()) {
            ClientStream<StreamingRecognizeRequest> clientStream;
            responseObserver =
                    new ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse>() {

                        ArrayList<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();

                        public void onStart(StreamController controller) {}

                        public void onResponse(StreamingRecognizeResponse response) {

                            try {
                                responses.add(response);
                                StreamingRecognitionResult result = response.getResultsList().get(0);
                                // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just
                                // use the first (most likely) one here.
                                SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
                                String transcript = alternative.getTranscript();
                                System.out.printf("Transcript : %s\n", transcript);
                                String newText = SpokenTextHistory.getInstance().getActualSpeechString() + " " + transcript;
                                SpokenTextHistory.getInstance().setActualSpeechString(newText);
                                controller.setLabelText(newText);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex){
                                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        public void onComplete() {
                        }

                        public void onError(Throwable t) {
                            System.out.println(t);
                        }
                    };

            clientStream = client.streamingRecognizeCallable().splitCall(responseObserver);

            RecognitionConfig recognitionConfig =
                    RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                            .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                            .setLanguageCode("pt-BR")
                            .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                            .build();
            StreamingRecognitionConfig streamingRecognitionConfig =
                    StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder().setConfig(recognitionConfig).build();

            StreamingRecognizeRequest request =
                    StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
                            .setStreamingConfig(streamingRecognitionConfig)
                            .build(); // The first request in a streaming call has to be a config

            clientStream.send(request);

            try {
                // SampleRate:16000Hz, SampleSizeInBits: 16, Number of channels: 1, Signed: true,
                // bigEndian: false
                AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(16000, 16, 1, true, false);
                DataLine.Info targetInfo =
                        new DataLine.Info(
                                TargetDataLine.class,
                                audioFormat); // Set the system information to read from the microphone audio
                // stream

                if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(targetInfo)) {
                    System.out.println("Microphone not supported");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                // Target data line captures the audio stream the microphone produces.
                micrunnable.targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
                micrunnable.targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
                micThread.start();

                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                while (!micrunnable.stopFlag) {

                    long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

                    if (estimatedTime >= 55000) {

                        clientStream.closeSend();
                        clientStream = client.streamingRecognizeCallable().splitCall(responseObserver);

                        request =
                                StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
                                        .setStreamingConfig(streamingRecognitionConfig)
                                        .build();

                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    } else {
                        request =
                                StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
                                        .setAudioContent(ByteString.copyFrom(micrunnable.sharedQueue.take()))
                                        .build();
                    }

                    clientStream.send(request);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I've been working hard for hours and have not found a solution that solves my problem.
It is worth mentioning that the environment variable is being set correctly.

Has anyone ever had this problem with Google? What should I do to fix this?

This is my envirounment variable creator:
PS: I`ve already tried use all google alternatives to validate credentials, but all return me errors.

```
package Controller.Autentication;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GoogleAuthentication {
    private static final String GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS";
    private static final String VoxSpeechFolder = ".vox";
    private static final String GoogleAuthenticationJsonFile = "VoxAuthentication.json";

    public static void setupGoogleCredentials() {
        String directory = defaultDirectory();
        directory += File.separator+VoxSpeechFolder;
        File voxPath = new File(directory);
        if (!voxPath.exists()) {
            voxPath.mkdirs();
        }
        ClassLoader classLoader = new GoogleAuthentication().getClass().getClassLoader();
        File srcFile = new File(classLoader.getResource(GoogleAuthenticationJsonFile).getFile());

        if(srcFile.exists()){
            try {
                String voxDestPath = defaultDirectory() + File.separator + VoxSpeechFolder +File.separator+ GoogleAuthenticationJsonFile;
                File destFile = new File(voxDestPath);
                copyFile(srcFile,destFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            Map<String,String> googleEnv = new HashMap<>();
            String path = defaultDirectory() +File.separator+ VoxSpeechFolder +File.separator+ GoogleAuthenticationJsonFile;
            googleEnv.put(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, path);
            setGoogleEnv(googleEnv);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream inStream ;
        OutputStream outStream ;
        System.out.println(destFile.getPath());
        if(destFile.createNewFile()){
            inStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

            }

            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();
        }
    }

    static String defaultDirectory()
    {
        String OS = getOperationSystem();
        if (OS.contains("WIN"))
            return System.getenv("APPDATA");
        else if (OS.contains("MAC"))
            return System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Application "
                    + "Support";
        else if (OS.contains("LINUX")) {
            return System.getProperty("user.home");
        }
        return System.getProperty("user.dir");
    }

    static String getOperationSystem() {
        return System.getProperty("os.name").toUpperCase();
    }
    protected static void setGoogleEnv(Map<String, String> newenv) throws Exception {
        try {
            Class<?> processEnvironmentClass = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment");
            Field theEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theEnvironment");
            theEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
            Map<String, String> env = (Map<String, String>) theEnvironmentField.get(null);
            env.putAll(newenv);
            Field theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment");
            theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
            Map<String, String> cienv = (Map<String, String>)     theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.get(null);
            cienv.putAll(newenv);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Class[] classes = Collections.class.getDeclaredClasses();
            Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
            for(Class cl : classes) {
                if("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap".equals(cl.getName())) {
                    Field field = cl.getDeclaredField("m");
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object obj = field.get(env);
                    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) obj;
                    map.clear();
                    map.putAll(newenv);
                }
            }
        }

        String genv = System.getenv(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS);
        System.out.println(genv);
    }
}
```